# Local Notifications in an Android Library

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm writing here because I'm facing a probleme that I could not resolve even after many researches and tries.

I'm currently developing an Android Library which consists only of java classes and fragment. The problem is I need to send Local Notifications to the user, and clicking on the notifications should send the user back to the activity where he was. At this point, my library sends the notifications just fine. But the click on the notification doesn't have any action.

In my notification reciver class (which extends the BroadcastReceiver class), when the notification appears, I create a Pending Intent but I don't know what I can give as parameters to send the user to the activity. I tried using intent filters but it give me no results

So **how can I have the notification sending back the user to the application ?** The best would be if I was able to have the notification sending back the user to the activity where the notification is created (but it's a fragment so...)

In an usual app, I would've an intent sending back the user to an activity class but my library needs to have only fragments.

Maybe there is no problem and the solution is easy since I'm new to notifications

If someone here have an idea thanks for helping me ! :D

And if my problem isn't clear (Because of my bad english as an example) don't hesitate to ask me to add informations ^^

**Edit from 29 April : **
I managed to achieve it by giving to my broadcast pending intent the canonical name of my class using :

```
mContext.getClass().getCanonicalName();
```

Once in my broadcast receiver class I just get the class from the name of the sending class :

```
Class<?> activityClass = null;
    try {
       activityClass = Class.forName(stringSourceClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check out below code...**

```
public BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              try {
                  String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

                  Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);

                  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                          .setContentTitle(title)
                          .setContentText("Hello")
                          .setAutoCancel(false)
                          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                  notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
          }
      };
```

Comment: You need to read the question. OP doesn't have an `Activity`, so he can't create an `Intent` using `YourActivity.class`. He has written a library containing POJOs and a Fragment.

Comment: David is right, I was not able to do that. I found a way though and will edit my post if someone have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

check the [Building a notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) page:

> ```
> Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
> ...
> // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
> // no need to create an artificial back stack.
> PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
>     PendingIntent.getActivity(
>     this,
>     0,
>     resultIntent,
>     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
> );
> ```

just put your activity in resultIntent

Comment: You need to read the question. OP doesn't have an `Activity`, so he can't create an `Intent` using `ResultActivity.class`. He has written a library containing POJOs and a Fragment.

Comment: David is right, I was not able to do that. I found a way though and will edit my post if someone have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

> how can I have the notification sending back the user to the
>   application ?

That's pretty simple: 
1. While creating intent for pending intent call addAction ("action_name") method;
2. In activity you want to call (in manifest file) inside intent-filter tag add `<action android:name="action_name>.`
Now when your notification try to launch activity it would send intent message to system, which would search activity with proper action and launch it.
P.S. action name must be unique for every application

Comment: Thanks, even if I didn't managed to make what I want using your answer, it was the most close answer